# App called from another app return data

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm wondering if it's possible to not only start another from the current app, but also have that called app return data to the calling app, particularly when it finishes. Is there some way they can communicate or perhaps have access to some common files? And if this is not possible, what ways could I use to get around this? I'd be writing both apps if that matters.

Update: If they can communicate, are there any size or format restrictions on the data passed back to the original app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `startActivityForResult()`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).